# Suse 10 - Same disk showed as IDE (hda) and SCSI (sda)

Tags: devices

I have a strange problem with disk detection. I installed a Suse 10 and I see the same disk (scsi) showed as `/dev/hda` and `/dev/sda`. Here the fdisk output:

```
sl0slmkmsd00:~ # fdisk -l /dev/hda

Disk /dev/hda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002751a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/hda1            2048      526335      262144   83  Linux
/dev/hda2   *      526336   209715199   104594432   83  Linux
sl0slmkmsd00:~ # fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002751a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      526335      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *      526336   209715199   104594432   83  Linux
```

This caused to me some LVM issues that I solved with a filter in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` but it doesn't seems to me a pretty solution.

Is there a better/correct way to solve this?